# MySQL: How to separate JOIN table into new row, and ORDER BY date from both tables

Tags: mysql

To be honest, it's so hard to think of the title of this situation.
Here's the situation:

Current query:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, IFNULL(do.quantity, 0) + IFNULL(r.quantity, 0) + IFNULL(sa.quantity,0) AS quantity, 
do.quantity AS do_quantity, r.quantity AS r_quantity, do.dateOfDelivery AS do_date, r.dateCreated AS r_date
FROM product
LEFT JOIN (SELECT dp.productId, dp.quantity, do.dateOfDelivery FROM delivery_product AS dp, delivery_order as do 
           WHERE do.id = dp.deliveryId AND do.deleted = 0 AND dp.deleted = 0 AND do.dateOfDelivery >= '2020-02-29' AND do.dateOfDelivery <= '2020-03-30') AS do
           ON do.productId = product.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rp.productId, rp.quantity, r.dateCreated FROM return_product AS rp, returns AS r
           WHERE r.id = rp.returnId AND r.deleted = 0 AND r.returnStatus = 'Completed' AND rp.deleted = 0 AND r.dateCreated >= '2020-02-29' 
           AND r.dateCreated <= '2020-03-30') AS r ON r.productId = product.id
WHERE product.code = 'PIP005'
ORDER BY do.dateOfDelivery
```

Result:
[image: Output]

I've JOIN-ed 3 tables in this output. 
Tables:

- Products
- Delivery_orders AS do
- Returns AS r

However, my expected result is:
p/s: `product.name` is using dummy value of `productA` in the image below

[image: expected output]

Is it possible to do this without creating a new table?

Comment: Can you show the input data? Why are you expecting `r_date` to be `NULL`? And why does `product.name` change?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978951/mysql-query-for-count-and-sum

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: "I've JOIN-ed 3 tables in this output..." -- Nope, you joined 6 tables.

Comment: @Barmar, the product.name should be the same, `productA` just a dummy in general. I expect `r_date` to be `NULL` because there's no `returns` record with the `do_date`

Comment: Then why isn't it the same in the two examples? How are we supposed to know which differences are significant and which are just dummy data?

Comment: @Barmar, just the `product.name` is dummy. My bad for didn't specify it in my question.

Comment: Why are you expecting to get `r_date = NULL` for the first 5 rows? If you're getting non-null `r_date`, it means there's a return for that product.

Comment: @Barmar, as the current result I got, it does return some value. However, the value is from 1 single entry from `returns` table. And I would like to have it in a new row, instead of mixing up with all the rows.

Comment: You should use `UNION`, not `JOIN`, to put deliveries and returns on different rows. But I'm not sure what you then expect to put in `quantity` if they're not on the same row any more.

Comment: I think you're right for using UNION. For the quantity, I think I will need to remove it as it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do all the joins in one query. Do a query to get deliveries, and a query to get returns, then combine them with `UNION`. Each query should have dummy values for the columns that come only from the other query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT product.id, product.name, do.quantity, 
           do.quantity AS do_quantity, 0 AS r_quantity, 
           do.dateOfDelivery AS do_date, NULL AS r_date
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dp.productId, dp.quantity, do.dateOfDelivery FROM delivery_product AS dp, delivery_order as do 
               WHERE do.id = dp.deliveryId AND do.deleted = 0 AND dp.deleted = 0 AND do.dateOfDelivery >= '2020-02-29' AND do.dateOfDelivery <= '2020-03-30') AS do
               ON do.productId = product.id
    WHERE product.code = 'PIP005'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT product.id, product.name, r.quantity, 
           0 AS do_quantity, r.quantity AS r_quantity, 
           NULL AS do_date, r.dateCreated AS r_date
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT rp.productId, rp.quantity, r.dateCreated FROM return_product AS rp, returns AS r
               WHERE r.id = rp.returnId AND r.deleted = 0 AND r.returnStatus = 'Completed' AND rp.deleted = 0 AND r.dateCreated >= '2020-02-29' 
               AND r.dateCreated <= '2020-03-30') AS r ON r.productId = product.id
    WHERE product.code = 'PIP005') AS x
ORDER BY IFNULL(x.do_date, x.r_date)
```

Comment: I'm giving it a try. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're solution is correct, but just one thing that you might want to edit. You missed the `FROM product` statement in 2nd query.